# Action on connected device in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, device, onchange

I have a Swing `JFrame` with some labels and buttons. I need to perform some actions when device is plugged. I do not know and didn't find whether I can use `ActionListener` or something like this.

Comment: From the not really clear things you posted in your question I can only provide this link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/

Comment: *"..when device is plugged."*  What device specifically?  It might be possible to periodically poll for the device using standard Java (no JNI/JNA).

Answer (score 2):

What you will need is information on the device driver and how to be able to write code to catch events from the device. Note that they may have a library for this, but it might be in another language such as C or C++, and this could possibly force you to write code in this language or use JNI or JNA to interface their library with Java or both.

Answer (score 1):

ActionListener is applied only to actions in buttos, menus, popup, etc.

I guess that you need create something using JNI to listen for specific events in SO.